# outlook and programming with C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I wish to use the my Microsoft Outlook Task list in my C# application. Do you have any idea if that is possible? Can you give me a starting point or some tips for this task?

many thanks!
ps: btw, now I'm using Microsoft office 2010 beta.

Comment: Use "Outlook Redemption". You're not even required to run Outlook for that as it will open task list directly through Extended MAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for Office 2010, but maybe this helps: [Outlook Integration in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rambab/OutlookIntegration10282006032802AM/OutlookIntegration.aspx)

Comment: I don't say it will not work. I just point out that the resource does not specifically target Office 2010.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! My misunderstanding then, I was afraid I had missed something like removed MAPI support in O2010...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) library.
Look at the [RDOTaskItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOTaskItem.htm) class.